# Why did this flagged question get into disputed status?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, disputed-flags

Consider Stack Overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887598/pls-help-me-for-creating-employee-attendance-management-using-c-sharp.

Does Stack Overflow allow this type of questions? So why did my flag get into disputed status?
I flagged it as too broad.

**EDIT:**

That's strange. The question is on hold now as too broad. But what about my flag which got into DISPUTED?

**EDIT:**

This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation.

Comment: what did you flag it as?

Comment: I flagged it as Too Broad

Comment: Someone else (likely not a moderator) disagreed with you, but I don't think you're wrong.  It definitely is too broad.

Comment: @Makoto Thank you. Is there no way to check it who disagreed and why? I don't find anything here to disagree with this quesion as per SO help center guidelines

Comment: Triage queue, probably. If the consensus is that the question "looks ok" or "should be improved", all the existing flags are automatically disputed.

Comment: Well, it's been put on hold now. Case closed.

Comment: @ArunA.S No case is still not closed. Question is on hold now as too broad. But what about my flag which got into DISPUTED?

Comment: Probably some careless reviewing. The question is clearly too broad. Whoever disputed your flag was either half asleep or didn't bother reading the question and blindly rejected your flag. What you did was the right thing.

Comment: @ArunA.S That's not so good. Yes it's absolutely careless review.

Comment: You won't get the disputed flag back and it doesn't count against you. I hate that too, but just get over it, it is not worth to think about it. It will happen to you much more often in the future ... .

Comment: @martin Thank you. Kind of agree with you. But still it's feel like something is not right with review process. It should be improved.

Comment: The question was deleted with 3 deletion votes from >20K users

Comment: @rene Yes right. But I feel my flag should not have went into DISPUTED.

Comment: Most likely it was disputed by people not paying that much attention. When you posted it here on Meta, everyone flocked to it, paid more attention, and corrected the egregious initial error (from other people).

Comment: Somebody disagreed with your flag; that's the very definition of "disputed".

Comment: Good old triage review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7844555

Comment: @BradLarson Where the "safe" option isn't really safe at all.  Need to make people commit. Maybe it should be "Close" or "leave Open"? Or even better "Question Asker Has to Improve" which is an implicit close vote.

Comment: A disputed flag just means someone disagreed. It is irrelevant who or why, as it has no impact (positive or negative) on your ztats.

Comment: Hi @KenWhite Definately I'm not worried about my stats. But I already said it before that something is not right and should be improved. Thank You

Answer (score 18):

*Disputed* flags have no significance when it comes to your stats. As you flag more, you will accumulate disputed flags. We all have a slightly different understanding of the rules. In this case, [a majority of reviewers found this post to be Salvageable but "Need Improvement" in the Triage queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7844555) which invalidated all active flags on the post (marking them disputed).

As you contribute, this will happen. Another thing you'll run into is bad audits. That's the downside of having a heavily community-moderated environment. Don't stress about it. If you need affirmation that you made the right decision, then you can post to meta (like you've done) or a less invasive approach would be to join the [tavern chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and ask for consensus from a few vets.

Comment: Note that the SO tavern is also still active (though there are far fewer people): http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks